# Hide element when click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide element when the checkbox is clicked.

Somehow it didn't work -

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="showAtidit()">
<p id="hidethis">
hide me
</p>
```

**js**

```
function showAtidit($)
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        alert("not hide");
        document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        alert("hide");
        document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wv97mpcp/108/

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You are redifining $ in `showAtidit($)`

Comment: see comment below. BTW - why the $ sign is problem? because it waits for parameter and didnt get one?

Comment: Because that is used by jQuery. Now you have redefined it as = undefined, so no longer represents the jQuery library

Comment: Got it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jquery just use `toggle()` :

```
function showAtidit()
{
   $('#hidethis').toggle();
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function showAtidit()
{
  $('#hidethis').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="showAtidit()">
<p id="hidethis">
hide me
</p>
```

Comment: No @JohnJs you should use jquery object `$('#hidethis')` instead of js object `document.getElementById( "hidethis" )` so you could use the jQuery function `toggle()`, else you'll get `.toggle is not a function` error..

Comment: can't use .toggle in javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

remove the $ in your function parameters and the problem will be fixed :)

```
function showAtidit()
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            alert("not hide");
            document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            alert("hide");
            document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
```

could also do it like this:

```
function showAtidit()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
          $("#hidethis").hide();
        } 
        else {
          $("#hidethis").show();
        }
    };
```

(have to add id to checkbox tho)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, toggle is the way to go, Here I am testing the checked:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#toggleP").on("click",function() {
    $("#hidethis").toggle(!this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleP">
<p id="hidethis">
hide me
</p>
```

If you want to look at the state when loading the page:

```
$(function(){
  $("#toggleP").on("change",function() {
    $("#hidethis").toggle(!this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out. I hope it will help

```js
$('#sample').on("change",showAtidit)
function showAtidit()
 {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
  {
   alert("not hide");
   document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'block';
  }
  else
  {
   alert("hide");
      
   document.getElementById( "hidethis" ).style.display = 'none';
  }
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <input id="sample" type="checkbox">
<p id="hidethis">
hide me
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(this).toggle()` is risky as you can guarentee the initial state of checkbox which may cause the checkbox not work as intended.

The actually problem with your code is the `$`  in the function variable.

You can see this is the issue by looking in the console on the jsfiddle you posted by pressing f12.

Here is a revised JSFiddle that will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/wv97mpcp/112/

Comment: You can test the state too